# androidのgoogle mapsアプリを設定から位置情報をoffにしたときにでる警告を実装する方法

Tags: android

Androidのgoogle mapsアプリを設定から位置情報をoffにしたときに出る警告と
同様の実装を行いたいのですが、公式のドキュメントをみましたが、わかりませんでした。

設定方法のURLなどをご存知の方がいましたら教えてください

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 質問自体は**端末**の位置情報(GPS)設定の状態を取得したい、だと思ったのですが、貼られた画像は「アプリにどの権限を許可するか」なので、両者の意味合いは異なってきます。

Comment: いえ、設定の状態を取得する方法は調べてわかりました。質問しているのはgoogle mapのアプリのこの位置情報の権限をoffにするとダイアログが表示されます。このダイアログの出し方がわからないのです。   公式アプリだから設定できているのでしょうか？

Comment: 私が書いているダイアログの画像を貼りました。質問が的確でなくすみません